# Trying to do a postrgres database migration using AWS DMS. Have successfully done full load but can't do full load + CDC

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, database-migration

I'm trying to complete a project of doing a postgres database migration from a linux amazon EC2 instance to RDS PostgreSQL. I have sucessfully completed a full load migration but I now want to delete it all and instead do a full load + CDC however this is consistently failing.

The error I receive is:
"Error Unable to use plugins to establish logical replication on source PostgreSQL instance. Follow all prerequisites for 'PostgreSQL as a source in DMS' from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html Stop Reason FATAL_ERROR Error Level FATAL"

Having looked at the weblink I believe I have:

```
set wal_level = logical
set max_replication_slots = 10 
set max_wal_senders = 10
set wal_sender_timeout = 0
```

and I believe I have given the user (postgres) superuser permissions.

I'll be honest and I don't know what those settings do but that's what the instructions say. Does anyone have any ideas what I could try next?